# Python Control Flow

Tags: python, if-statement

For the following code:

```
def isString(x):
  if type(x)==str:
    return True
  return False
```

When I input a string into the parameter, after returning True, why wouldn't it also then return False? I'm new to Python and I'm confused because I assumed it would then return False because it is out of the for loop, however it doesn't.

Comment: Additionally, the pythonic way to do this is `isinstance(x, str)`

Comment: @Hernan in Python 2.x, normally it's `isinstance(x, basestring)` that's required...

Comment: @JonClements: Good point. If you want to check `isinstance(x, (str, unicode))` in Python 2.3 - 2.7 use basestring as a shortcut. If you want to check only for str, then use `isinstance(x, str)`. In Python 3.x there is no such distinction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is the same for any language. The return statement means return from the function, giving an optional value back. It can only return once. In this case it returns out of the conditional statement.

BTW, for type checking like that use the `is` operator.

```
if type(x) is str:
    return True
```

But, in fact, the real recommended way to do string type checking is:

```
if isinstance(x, str):
    return True
```

However, since it's so short you don't really need t write your function for this at all (except for learning purposes). Just use `isinstance(x, str)` where you would have otherwise wrote `isString(x)`.

Answer (score 1):

By the way, there is no for-loop in your code

When a function returns something - anything - it's done. The `return` statement means that the function exits; no more processing whatsoever.

If the type of `x` is `str`, then the function returns `True`. However, if the type of `x` is not `str`, then the if-statement is never entered, and `True` is not returned. Instead, the function continues to the next line after the if-statement, namely `return False` -- and the function returns `False`

Answer (score 1):

The `return` statement terminates the function. Once you return, the function stops.